Livewire Tinymce 7 not loaded when opening modal nya wire-element/modal
I have 2 file,
Index
Modal add
In index there a script for textarea wysiwyg tinymce and loaded successfull, and there a button, when that button clicked  a modal show with a textarea form, and i want that textarea (inside file modal) became wysiwyg Tinymce, so im add the script Tinymce.init() inside that file modal but when opening that modal.
Tinymce 7 not loaded when im opening modal created nya wire-element/modal, even im put the script tinymce.init();
Inside file modal
@push('style') 
   @vite('..... script.js') 
@endpush

@push('script') 
  <script> 
     tinymce.init({
      selector: '#editor'
     }) 
      ..... code
  </script>
@endpush

<div>
   ....... code
   <div wire:ignore>
     <textarea wire:model="model" id="editor"></textarea>
   </div>
   ........ code
</div>

When im click a buuton to open this modal, tinymce not loaded..
or because it same content? nad must different each textarea and tinymce??
Tinymce loaded inside modal when im click button and modal pop up
